# Not able to deserialize the JSON response

Tags: java, json, serialization

How to deserialize the below json response with java pojo class.

**JSON Response**

```
"details": 
  {
     "distance": 14745,
     "km": 14.745,
     "steps": 16804,
     "active_time": 11927,
     "longest_active": 2516,
     "inactive_time": 32760,
     "longest_idle": 27180,
     "calories": 1760.30480012,
     "bmr_day": 1697.47946931,
     "bmr": 1697.47946931,
     "bg_calories": 1099.9439497,
     "wo_calories": 388.506116077,
     "wo_time": 11484,
     "wo_active_time": 3902,
     "wo_count": 2,
     "wo_longest": 2516,
     "tz": "America/Los Angeles",
     "tzs": 
     [
        [1384963500, "America/Phoenix"],
        [1385055720, "America/Los_Angeles"]
     ]
 }
```

I have written the below pojo catch for deserializing the JSON response.

**Response.java**

```
public class Response {

private Distance distance;
}

Distance.java
 public class Distance{ private int distance;
    private double km;
    private int steps;
    private int active_time;
     private int longest_active;
    private int inactive_time;
    private int longest_idle;
    private int calories;
    private int bmr_day;
    private int bmr;
    private int bg_calories;
    private int wo_calories;
    private int wo_time;
    private int wo_active_time;
   private int wo_count;
   private int wo_longest;
    private int sunrise;
    private int sunset;
    private String tz;
    private String[] tzs;
    private String hourly_totals;
  }
```

I am getting the below exception,

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
atSource: java.io.PushbackInputStream@e6819e;(through reference chain: Details["tzs"]); 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
```

How to overcome this.

Comment: try to change as String[] tzs as List<Map<String,String>>

Comment: dont you need a class TimeZone to match that part of the JSON ?

Comment: `tzs` in your JSON response is not a string array (as in your `Response` class), but an array of string arrays.

Comment: It's not even an array of string arrays since it has `Number` also... So its basically an array of Object arrays...

Comment: @Codebender so is it something related to my first comment ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia you are exactly right... Its a list of timezones..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class to match the arrays of timezones

```
public class TimeZoneClass {
    private Object[] tz_values ;
}
```

And in

change this

```
private String[] tzs;
```

to this

```
private TimeZoneClass[] tzs;
```

Comment: I think you should be using an `Object[]` instead of 2 different fields in TimeZoneClass... Because only `JSONObjects` will be parsed into different fields... But here it's an `JSONArray` which contains the ID and name.

Comment: @Codebender feel free to edit my answer or post your own since you deserve credit ;-)

Comment: @Codebender Can you please edit the answer. I running out of time

Comment: @Karthik I have changed the class according to codebender comments test it and let me know

Comment: @Karthik, Mauricio already edited... If that doesn't work you will have to use `private Object tzs;` in your distance class.

Comment: @Codebender `private Object[][] tzs` maybe ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia, an `Object[]` is also an `Object`. Afterall everything is an `Object`. So I thought just an Object should work.. But he can try with various types if that doesn't work...

Comment: @MauricioGracia   The answer worked like like gem. You both gentlemen made my day. I have a another problem with this response shall I edit the same question?

Comment: @Codebender The answer worked like like gem. You both gentlemen made my day. I have a another problem with this response shall I edit the same question? –

Comment: @Codebender Ok I  will post

Comment: @Karthik after posting feel free to post a link here

Comment: @MauricioGraciahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209868/json-deserialization-throwing-exception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-u

Comment: @Codebender http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209868/json-deserialization-throwing-exception-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-u