# JSON deserialization throwing exception - Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, serialization, arraylist

The below is my JSON response,

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@bce1d9; line: 1, column: 556] (through reference chain: com.totalHours["data"]->com.totalHours["hourly_totals"])

```
 "totalHours": 
  {
     "hourly_totals": 
     {
        "2013112101":
        {
           "distance": 1324,
           "calories": 90.0120018125,
           "steps": 1603,
           "active_time": 793,
           "inactive_time": 220,
           "longest_active_time": 302,
           "longest_idle_time": 780
        },
        "2013112101":
        {
           "distance": 626,
           "calories": 47.0120018125,
           "steps": 455,
           "active_time": 246,
           "inactive_time": 260,
           "longest_active_time": 203,
           "longest_idle_time": 650
        },
        ... more hours ...
     }
```

I have took a pojo class like below, I am getting an exception when I try to deserialize the my json data.

```
public class totalHours{
private List<String> hourly_totals;
}
```

But, I don't know whether to take a List because there is no array in response. What will be the other options to try out for.

Comment: there's no array in your JSON. Can you change it?

Comment: @Onheiron Then how to deserialize the response. Any idea?

Comment: Is this really the entire response you are getting?

Comment: Are you having duplicate keys `"2013112101"` in your JSON???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hourly_totals` is an object from an hour represented as a string to another object, to `Map<String,T>` , where T is a POJO class representing the data for one hour, would look like a natural choice.